# Prevent R source code from export to html

Tags: r, rnotebook

I'd like to prevent the R source code of my R notebook not only from  not being displayed, but I want it to disappear from the html file entirely. Same for the [CODE] button in the top right corner.

So far, I've only found

```
code_folding: hide
```

but it only collapses the code, or

```
echo=FALSE
```

in the chunk options, but this does not make the button at the top go away.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you considered using html_document instead of notebook?

Comment: Aaaah, thanks! No, I hadn't thought of that.